# Calculate driving distance from gps coordinates points

Tags: gis, postgis

I've got courier tracking android app, which posts every 30s gps coords of the courier to a postgis database.

We need to calculate how many kilometers couriers do in order to provide them gas(petrol) refund.

How would you do that, fellow developers?

Answer (score 0):

Sum the [great-circle distances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) between consecutive measurement points to get an approximation (lower bound actually) for the distance traveled.

You can probably also get away (and get better numerical stability) with calculating the [3D ECEF positions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF) from the spherical coordinates and summing the Euclidean distances between these points because it's pretty much impossible to cover a significant curvature on Earth in 30 seconds.

Comment: I guess it means that when couriers takes a turn around like: ---O---

Comment: Can't edit above: I guess it means that when courier takes a turn around then the distance between two points will not include whole road but straight line between points, loosing some accuracy, but it's probably rarely the case... It could be   compensated by more often gps coords posts to server, is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. If you have an accelerometer and gyroscope, you can use inertial navigation between GPS measurements to get a more accurate estimate of the actual distance traveled. But implementing this will be more complicated than just querying GPS coordinates.